# SQL Developer: how to order NUMerically and replacing a null value with CHAR

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    department_id AS department,
    COUNT(employee_id) AS "total employees"
FROM 
    employees 
GROUP BY 
    department_id
ORDER BY 
    department_id;
```

Output:

[image]

(Based on HR database) ^the code is listing every individual department, counting the employees per department and ordering numerically

But I need to replace the "null" value with some text, I've tried using TO_CHAR but when I do it I can't order the departments numerically I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The standard function for this is `coalesce()`.

Comment: Do you mean NVL? i've tried but i can only use it when i use the TO_CHAR function, loosing the asc numeric order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you want is:

```
SELECT COALESCE(department_id, 'Some text') AS department,
       COUNT(employee_id) AS total_employees
FROM employees 
GROUP BY department_id
ORDER BY department_id;
```

If `department_id` is a number, then convert it to a string first:

```
SELECT COALESCE(TO_CHAR(department_id), 'Some text') AS department,
       COUNT(employee_id) AS total_employees
FROM employees 
GROUP BY department_id
ORDER BY department_id;
```

Notes:

- `COALESCE()` is the SQL standard function for replacing a `NULL` value.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never necessary when using `GROUP BY`.
- This assumes that no department's id is `'some text'`.

Comment: im so ignorant i HAVE to learn more, i had no idea how coalesce works, thanks you so much!!